# Selectively serialize properties of an instance into JSON

Tags: c#, json.net

I've got some JSON file containing a somewhat weird format. I have to read, modify and save this format for my project. Unfortunately, I don't have any influence to the given format.

The strange thing about this format is that all entities in this structure have a unique identifier, which is (invalidly) called "$id". These instances can also be referred to by their id instead of the complete set of their properties. In this case, there is no "$id" but instead there's a "$ref" field, containing an already defined entity. Look at the (shortened) example below:

```
{
    "$id": "1",
    "StyleName": "Standard",
    "Style": {
        "$id": "2",
        "ShapeStyle": {
            "$id": "3",
            "Background": {
                "$id": "4",
                "Color": {
                    "$id": "5",
                    "A": 255,
                    "R": 68,
                    "G": 84,
                    "B": 106
                }
            }
        },
        "RightEndCapsStyle": {
            "$id": "6",
            "Background": {
                "$id": "7",
                "Color": {
                    "$ref": "5"
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To handle this, I've created a C# base class *Entity* for all JSON data classes. This base class maintains a registry of ids, so that it can easily find the instance for a given *$ref*. Here's the code:

```
public class Entity
{
    public static Dictionary<string, Entity> Registry = new Dictionary<string, Entity>();

    private string key = string.Empty;

    [JsonProperty("$id", Order = -2)]
    [DefaultValue("")]
    public string Key
    {
        get { return key; }
        set
        {
            key = value;
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(key)) Registry.Add(key, this);
        }
    }

    [JsonProperty("$ref")]
    public string RefKey { get; set; }

    [JsonIgnore]
    public bool IsReference => !string.IsNullOrEmpty(RefKey);

    [JsonIgnore]
    public Entity RefEntity
    {
        get
        {
            Entity entity = null;
            if (IsReference && !Registry.TryGetValue(RefKey, out entity))
            {
                throw new ApplicationException("Referenced entity not found!");
            }
            return entity;
        }
    }
}
```

The JSON class hiearchy looks like this:

```
public class RootObject: Entity
{
    public string StyleName { get; set; }
    public StyleRoot Style { get; set; }
}

public class StyleRoot: Entity
{
    public Style ShapeStyle { get; set; }
    public Style RightEndCapsStyle { get; set; }
}

public class Style: Entity
{
    public Background Background { get; set; }
}

public class Background: Entity
{
    public Color Color { get; set; }
}

public class Color: Entity
{
    public int A { get; set; }
    public int R { get; set; }
    public int G { get; set; }
    public int B { get; set; }
}
```

So far, so good. Now to my questions:

1. `[JsonProperty("$id")]` and `[JsonProperty("$ref")]` do not work since *$id* and *$ref* are no valid JSON field name identifiers. Currently, I am using a regular expression to replace them by something valid and re-replace them afterwards back to what they used to be. But this is sluggish. I wonder if I could use the `NamingStrategy` to achieve the same. But I didn't succeed. Remember, I need both ways, deserialization and serialization.
2. The serialization is an even harder issue. If I serialize my structure as is, I end up with both, `"$id":` and `"$ref":` fields in each instance. What is more, together with the referenced item all other fields are serialized with default values. The easiest way was to simply set `DefaultValueHandling.IgnoreAndPopulate` in the `JsonSerializerSettings`. But this way, all default values are stripped from the output which leads to unexpected behavior. I tried to go with a `ContractResolver` but failed because this is local to the current property and cannot take the surrounding entity into account. Is there any other way to implement a custom serialization strategy?

Tough questions, I know. And a lot of stuff to read and understand. But if it would have been easy, I wouldn't have taken the effort to put it all up here. Your help is desperately needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These `$id`s and `$ref`s are used by Json.NET internally when [`PreserveReferencesHandling` mode](http://www.newtonsoft.com/json/help/html/PreserveObjectReferences.htm) is enabled. You don't need to care about them, just define your `RootObject`, `StyleRoot`, etc. classes normally without that `Entity` base class and set `PreserveReferencesHandling` mode in `JsonSerializerSettings`. Json.NET will deal with the `$id`s and `$ref`s under the hood and create an object network preserving original reference structure:

```
var obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(json,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.All });
```

Serialization may also be done in the preserve references handling mode:

```
var json = JsonConvert.SerializeObject(obj,
    new JsonSerializerSettings { PreserveReferencesHandling = PreserveReferencesHandling.Objects });
```

Demo: https://dotnetfiddle.net/TygMDZ

N.B. In your input data sample the `"$ref"` attribute contains a numeric value whilst Json.NET writes and expects `"$ref"` attributes to have string values. May it be so that you accidentally posted JSON text changed in the course of some experiments on it?

Comment: Perfect! Works for me.
You're right about the "$ref" value. I've stripped a lot of text for it to be more compact. I had to do some manual editing...
What's the difference between PreserveReferenceHandling.Object and PreserveReferenceHandling.All, by the way?